# orderBy() Specific Order Defined by Array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 types of phones that are defined in an array by ID. `['1. Primary', '2. Home', '3. Mobile', '4. Work']`. Users must have one filled out at minimum but could be multiple. We don't know which one(s) they decided to enter.

In this specific case I want to setup a scopeFunction that pulls the Mobile Phone. If the user doesn't have a mobile phone, I want to setup a fallback to Primary, if no Primary, Home, etc..

```
public function scopeMobile($query, $uuid) {
    return $query->phone()
        ->where('uuid', $uuid)
        ->whereIn('phone_type_id', [3,1,2,4]);
}
```

Function Calling that Scope

```
public static function mobile_phone($uuid) {
    return self::mobile($uuid)->get();
}
```

I'm looking for a way to achieve this type of scenario where the order will fallback matching the `->whereIn([3,1,2,4])`.  I know this isn't valid but something similar to this `->orderBy([3,1,2,4])`.

If I do an `->orderBy('phone_type_id', 'desc')` it will pull in order of 4,3,2,1 and `->orderBy('phone_type_id', 'asc')` will pull an order of 1,2,3,4.

Is it possible or how can I get this to order as [3,1,2,4] within the scopeFunction?

Comment: You could add an order attribute or use `->orderByRaw('FIELD(phone_type_id,3,1,2,4)')`

Comment: @Aless55 that worked great! what do you mean by an order attribute?

Comment: if the order is dynamic you might want to add an attribute called order for each phone_type, so phone_type with id 1 has order 2 for example, id 2 has order 3, id 3 has order 1 and id 4 has order 4. But if the order is always the same you can also jsut hardcode it with the method above. I see it worked, so I would go the easy way :D